# Form validation not working with Bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I am using Bootstrap validator to ensure all fields are filled when submitting a form. But my validator is not working as expected!

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3v3011e0/

If you play with it and submit the form with all fields empty, and change one of them to not empty, then all fields become green. This should not happen. It should only be green for the field that is working properly. As seen in this picture, username and password are empty but show up as green. Also the icon only shows for username. How do I fix this?

[image]

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">

    <input id="userField" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter user name" class="form-control" />

    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a password" class="form-control" />

    <select id="myPicker" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select number</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      username: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
          }
        }
      },
      password: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The password is required and cannot be empty'
          }
        }
      },
      num: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Number is required and cannot be empty'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was working with the old version of this plugin, bootstrapValidator as it came with a theme I was using, SmartAdmin.

First, there are two versions of this plugin.

formvalidation.io (paid version), bootstrapValidator (free version, up until .5.2?)

Anyways they are different and the documentation is different so make sure you are using the docs for the correct one.

The problem this user is having is the HTML markup is incorrect. Each field must be separated with class ".form-group", when using default initialization of the plugin.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="userField" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter user name" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a password" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="myPicker" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select number</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3v3011e0/7/

If this is not possible, try emulating the initialization of the complex form example.
http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/examples/complex-form/